# kalus rosh in a bes midrash

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

A happy Adar to all!

[The משנה in אבות](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%92_%D7%99%D7%91) says "הֱוֵי קַל לָרֹאשׁ", on which [the רע״ב writes](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%92#.D7.9E.D7.A9.D7.A0.D7.94_.D7.99.D7.91):

> לפני אדם גדול זקן ויושב בראש בישיבה, הוי קל לעבוד עבודתו ולשמש לפניו

Thus we see that one should exercise קלות ראש in a ישיבה (i.e., בית מדרש).

Yet [the גמרא in מגילה](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=1467&size=1) says

> בתי כנסיות אין נוהגין בהן קלות ראש

and we know from [רב פפי](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=1465&size=1) (whose opinion the גמרא says makes the most sense, q.v.) that a בית מדרש is even greater than a בית כנסת, so קלות ראש is certainly forbidden in a בית מדרש!

How do we resolve this apparent contradiction?

---

**This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The באר היטב answers as follows:

[The conclusion of the גמרא](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=1468&size=1) is

> אין נוהגין בהן קלות ראש ומאי ניהו חשבונות

Remember what the רע״ב wrote: that it is appropriate to exercise קלות ראש by serving the ראש ישיבה. That's true, but not if you're doing it because you have some sort of חשבונות.

---

Biographical note:

The source for this answer is the באר היטב. This is not the *Baer Hetev* ("explain well"), written by *Rav Y'huda Ashkenazi*, but the *B'er Hetev* ("well well"), written by *Rav Shmerl Almoni* when he was a chaplain for the Army Corps of Engineers. He authored many other works, including *Halel Nirtza* on the merits of being a Jewish servant. He died young, לא עלינו, leaving his wife pregnant with identical quadruplet boys, each of whom grew up to be a great תלמיד חכם. She named them after the ברכות יעקב: *Binyamin Vulf*, *Y'huda Leib*, *Naftali Hirsch*, and *Yisachar Eizl*.

Comment: [possibly related](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4990/170)